# Получение данных из rtkQuery

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Всем привет у меня есть фукнция из rtkQuery, из которой я получаю состояние isLoading. Мне нужно это состояние использовать в другом (родительском) компоненте. Но я не хочу прокидывать несколько props, т.к. это против концепции redux.

```
const [addCommentForArticle, { isLoading: isLoadingUpdate }] =
      useAddCommentForArticleMutation();
```

по идеи isLoading должен храниться в stor, но вопрос в том как его получить?

Вот способ получения данных из rtkquery store по get запросу. как сделать так же для мутации?

```
const articleApi = rtkApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    //! типа данные с сервера, и типа параметров (нет)
    getArticleById: build.query({
      query: (articleId) => ({
        url: `/articles/${articleId}`,
        params: {
          _expand: 'user',
        },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetArticleByIdQuery } = articleApi;

//! получение из store
export const useGetArticleById = (articleId: string) =>
  createSelector(
    articleApi.endpoints.getArticleById.select(articleId),
    (usersResult) => usersResult.data,
  );

//   const testData = useAppSelector(useGetArticleByIdData);
```

Answer (score 0):

например вот так. (предпологаю есть еще варианты)

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [_, { isLoading }] = useSomeMut({
    fixedCacheKey: "xyz",
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  const [f, { data, isLoading }] = useSomeMut({
    fixedCacheKey: "xyz",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    f(".............");
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};
```